# derivative of complex function of higher order

Tags: calculus

i am not able to find the value of the 2014th order derivative of the function $f(z)=z^2e^{kz}$ at zero. Any help will be appreciated. thank you

Comment: sorry it is  $f(z)=z^{2}e^{kz}$

Comment: Is it $\exp^{kz}$ or $\exp^{k} z$?

Comment: ok... now it is fine

Comment: @user148789 Please do edit directly your questions when you discover a typo or a mistake.

Comment: Hint: Expand the exponential function in a power series.

Comment: I think the solution must be this: $k^{2012}e^{kz}(k^{2}z^{2}+2*2014kz+2014*2013)$

Answer (score 2):

Expand $z^{2}e^{kz}$ as a Taylor series:

$$z^2 + \frac{k^1}{1!}z^{1+2} + \frac{k^2}{2!}z^{2+2} + \frac{k^3}{3!}z^{3+2} + …$$

Now differentiate it 2014 times. Terms before $z^{2012+2}$ will differentiate down to $0$ and terms after $z^{2012+2}$ will differentiate down to multiples of $z$, which (since you are looking for the value at $z=0$) are also zero. So the only relevant term is the $z^{2012+2}$ one itself, which, 2014 times differentiated, becomes

$$2014! \frac{k^{2012}}{2012!}$$

…which you can simplify for yourself.

It is interesting to attempt the alternative, which is to differentiate $z^{2}e^{kz}$ itself, because you will end up with the coefficient of $z^0$ being a complicated series, and you can impress everyone including yourself by being able to show that the sum of the series is $2014 \times 2013 \times k^{2012}$.

Comment: You can say it shortly: $f^{(2014)}(0)$ is the coefficient of $z^{2014}/2014!$ in the Tayor development.

Answer (score 0):

As commented:

$$z^2e^{kz}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{n+2}k^n}{n!}=z^2+kz^3+\frac{k^2z^4}2+\ldots+\frac{k^{2013}z^{2015}}{(2013)!}+\ldots$$

Since the above series has infinite radius of convergence you can differentiate it elementwise wherever you want. Now, when differentiated $\;2016\;$ times at $\;z=0\;$, what exactly doesn't vanish?

Answer (score 0):

If you set $z=0$ at the equation mentioned in the comment:

$$k^{2012}e^{kz}(k^{2}z^{2}+2\times 2014kz+2014\times 2013)$$
Then you get:

$$2014\times 2013k^{2012}$$

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is a simpler solution, you can evaluate all derivatives explicitly.

Develop the $n^{th}$ derivative of the product by the binomial formula, giving just three terms

$$\left(z^2e^{kz}\right)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left(z^2\right)^{(k)}\left(e^{kz}\right)^{(n-k)}=\binom n0z^2k^ne^{kz}+\binom n12zk^{n-1}e^{kz}+\binom n22k^{n-2}e^{kz}.$$

Evaluated at $z=0$, this yields $$n(n-1)k^{n-2}.$$

---

Even better, you can use the fact that $(x^d)^{(k)}(0)=d!\delta_{k-d}$ (Kroncker delta) to get directly

$$\left.\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left(z^2\right)^{(k)}\left(e^{kz}\right)^{(n-k)}\right|_{z=0}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk2!\delta_{k-d}k^{(n-k)}=2!\binom n2k^{n-2}.$$